# Chat "Rejoin favorite rooms" has gone missing

Tags: support, chat, user-interface

I have a number of chat rooms marked as favorite and I was quite accustomed to using the "Rejoin favorite rooms" chat feature to join them all at once. However, sometime over the past few days, that button has gone missing.

[image: Where is Rejoin favorite rooms?]

(Note: Most of the chat rooms I've favorited are private rooms. This may or may not have anything to do with it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button is only visible if you're in no other room than the one you're looking at. The equivalent button on your [favorite tab](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms?tab=favorite) is still there, though.

Comment: That's... confusing. What I'd really like is for this button to always be there, if I'm not currently in _all_ of my favorite rooms.

Comment: If you ask me, I actually find that button annoying. The only use case it's for is "you have one room bookmarked, and once you join it, you want to rejoin the rest of your favorite rooms." I would hate if it kept sitting there; in particular since the functionality still exist (where it *really* belongs: on the favorites tab). Feel free to open a feature request though, if you think you can make a good case and suggest a non-annoying implementation, to see if there's community support for this.

Answer (score 0):

The "Rejoin Favorite Rooms" button only appears when you have left all of your favorite rooms. In the picture, it seems that you are still in "The Comms Room".